# iDrac6 Email Alert Problem

Tags: email, alerts, drac

I'm trying to setup the email alerts on the iDrac6 Express on an R610, but when i run the test it just says "Sending Failed". Platform Event Filter Alerts are enabled.

The network setup is:

- 192.168.1.22/255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS: 192.168.1.1
- SMTP: 192.168.1.1

Exim is listening 192.168.1.1 and is set to allow mail on 192.168/16. There's nothing in the exim logs about connections from the drac. Is there a way to get the drac to give more information about why it's sending failed?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many times when I'd sniff traffic. In this case I'd get my sniffer situated to capture the iDRAC's connection to the LAN and see if it's even sending anything to the LAN at all. While you could capture traffic on the SMTP server I'd be more apt to watch what the iDRAC card is saying first.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put in the DNS name of your domain to get this to work.

Under Idrac Settings Network / Security
network.
DNS name.  Put in your DNS domain name.  Idrac will be able to send out the emails.

Answer (score 0):

The iDRAC6 supports telnet connections. I wonder if it's possible to telnet into the iDRAC6 and make an SMTP connection from there to your Exim server to test sending an email.

If that's not possible, then I'm in agreement with Evan. Set up a packet sniffer on another machine and mirror the iDRAC6 switch port to the packet sniffer machine port and see what's coming out of the iDRAC6, if anything. If your switch doesn't support port mirroring, you can connect a hub in between the iDRAC6, the packet sniffer machine, and the switch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update iDrac6 to the latest version
2. Access to iDrac6 using the web interface and log in
3. In IDrac settings > Network/Security

Common Settings

- "DNS DRAC Name" contains the name of the server
- "DNS domain" is an existing domain name
- The check boxes are not activated

IPv4 Settings

- All settings are set up correctly

Apply the changes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing in this link works for you (https://www.prolved.com/rac0225-sending-test-mail-failed/) then try this, it worked for me: https://www.kniko.net/rac0225-sending-the-test-mail-failed/  .

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please post the relevant parts of links alongside them as links can change or go dead which would invalidate an otherwise relevant answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/501728)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue.